# SQL Server 2008 Get Records where Group Count = 1

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Not sure how to approach this.

This is how the table is populated...(see screenshot) The UserID_Combo in the table has multiple records. That field is made up of a GUID (the UserID) and the Date and Time of the visit. For each click on the page that UserID_Combo appears in the table. If the user returns the next day the same UserID but with a different Date and Time appear in the table. As shown in the screenshot 05b user Date and Time stamps are different which means they hit the page twice.  At the end of the month I want to find out which user hit the page just once. In the data I would like to return the data for User 057bd as highlighted?

This is my SQL Server 2008 query that produced the results:

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT UserID + '_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 110) + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 14), '-', '_'), 
                      ' ', '_'), ':', '_') AS UserID_Combo, UserID, COUNT(UserID) AS UserID_Count, wfoKey
FROM         dbo.tbl_User_Statistics2
GROUP BY UserID + '_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 110) + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 14), '-', '_'), ' ', '_'), ':', '_'), 
                      UserID, wfoKey
HAVING      (wfoKey = 'df718d2b98')
ORDER BY UserID
```

[image: duplicate groups]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to `group by` the `UserId` and choose records where the date only appears one (I think).  If you are using SQL Server 2008 or later.  This returns UserIds that hit the page on only one date:

```
select UserID
from dbo.tbl_User_Statistics2
group by UserID
having count(distinct cast(wfoStartTime as date)) = 1
order by UserId;
```

If you only want `UserId`s with *exactly* one hit:

```
select UserID
from dbo.tbl_User_Statistics2
group by UserID
having count(*) = 1
order by UserId;
```

Comment: Added your second sql stmt to a derived table to isolate the records in a result.  Thanks Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `HAVING CLAUSE` for that with `GROUP BY`.

This will be your query:

```
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT UserID + '_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 110) + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 14), '-', '_'), 
                  ' ', '_'), ':', '_') AS UserID_Combo, UserID, COUNT(UserID) AS UserID_Count
FROM  dbo.tbl_User_Statistics2
GROUP BY UserID + '_' + REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 110) + ' ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), wfoStartTime, 14), '-', '_'), ' ', '_'), ':', '_'), 
UserID
HAVING COUNT(UserID) = 1
ORDER BY UserID
```

Comment: How would I filter the data on another field. Tried and returns the duplicates. Edited original question (see above).

Comment: That filter will go in your WHERE clause.